# How to run script during npm version

Tags: javascript, npm

Is there a way to run a script during `npm version`, that is running after the release number was increased but before creating and pushing the git tag?

Comment: I had the same problem, I created a grunt task to do both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `version` script that will be called once the package version is increased but before the commit and tag.

```
"scripts": {
  "version": "./your_script"
}
```

Check the order of execution according to the [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) documentation. Below you can see the interesting excerpt, in particular point 4:

> 1. Check to make sure the git working directory is clean before we get
>      started. Your scripts may add files to the commit in future steps.
>      This step is skipped if the --force flag is set.
> 2. Run the preversion script. These scripts have access to the old version in package.json. A typical use would be running your full test suite before deploying. Any files you want added to the commit should be explicitly added using git add.
> 3. Bump version in package.json as requested (patch, minor, major, etc).
> 4. Run the version script. These scripts have access to the new version in package.json (so they can incorporate it into file headers in generated files for example). Again, scripts should explicitly add generated files to the commit using git add.
> 5. Commit and tag.
> 6. Run the postversion script. Use it to clean up the file system or automatically push the commit and/or tag.

This functionality was introduced in npm [v2.13.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v2.13.0). See [version: allow scripts to add files to the commit](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/582f170) for more info.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the `version` script is not listed [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)?

Comment: It's actually listed along with the `preversion` script, but it's not clear the difference between them
`preversion, version: Run BEFORE bump the package version.` Maybe it would be clear if they were in different points.

Comment: It is correct that the `version` script runs before the Git commit, but you have to add the changed files inside your script:

```{ 
  "scripts": { 
    "version": "npm run build:genversion && git add -A dist" 
  } 
}```

Otherwise the changed file won't be committed in the version commit.


I found the info here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-version#description

Answer (score 0):

In this page https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts there are some scripts that you can use:

> - preversion, version: Run BEFORE bump the package version.
> - postversion: Run AFTER bump the package version.

With this you can add one of these scripts in your package.json:

```
"scripts": { "postversion" : "./your_script" }
```

Also, you can take a look in the hooks: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts

Comment: But still, the doc is not clear if `preversion` is befor or after tagging, do you know for sure that it will run before tagging/pushing?

Comment: No, sorry. I saw the docs a few days ago and did not do any testing. I thought it might help when i saw your question

Comment: At the current day, `preversion` is the only one running before the bump. `version` runs after the bump and `postversion` runs even later, after the commit and tag has happened.